# Start a process with a command line parameter of another executable

Tags: c#, process, command-line-arguments

I'm trying to pass an .exe to another through C# code.

Here's my code so far:

```
string ex1 = System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath.ToString() + "\\dev\\psm.exe";
string ex2 = System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath.ToString() + "\\dev\\Application\\app.exe";

ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
startInfo.FileName = ex1;
startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
startInfo.Arguments = ex2;

try
{
    Process.Start(startInfo);
}
catch
{
}
```

Which argument would work as dragging a file onto the application?
 
 **Details:**  
When you run psm.exe normally, it prompts for file name and directory. 
[image: Running psm.exe]

However, when you drag an approved app on psm.exe,
[image: Running file with psm.exe] 
it loads the app automatically. [image: Running app]

How can this be done with C#?

Answer (score 0):

You can run another app synchronously like this:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process myapp = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
myapp.StartInfo.FileName = ex1;
myapp.StartInfo.Arguments = ex2;
myapp.Start();
myapp.WaitForExit();
```

Depending on how the app you want to launch expects the command line arguments to be passed, you may need this for the arguments:

```
myapp.StartInfo.Arguments = String.Format("/MyArgumentName={0}", ex2);
```

That would be the equivalent of:

```
c:\MyApplicationStartupPath\dev\psm.exe /MyArgumentName=c:\MyApplicationStartupPath\Application\App.exe
```

Be sure to match the way app.exe expects the parameters in your StartInfo.Arguments

Comment: This would launch psm.exe and pass it the argument app.exe

Comment: Didn't work.Just opens the first .exe then terminates.

Comment: So you aren't editing the code of the ps sim?  In that case how about something like: Process.Start(@"c:\sim\psm.exe", "\"c:\mypath\app.exe\"");

Comment: If you're path has spaces in it you may have to wrap inverted commas around the app.exe path because the command line arguments don't usually like spaces